# LinearLayout above ImageView not getting displayin Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have ImageView which needs to be shown in full height available. However at top i have created LinearLayout which contains Text and Image. I want it to display at top but also want to image to fit screen. I have linear layout at bottom and its working fine.

This is my code for LinearLayout which i want to show at top. I have hidden actionbar

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Testing"
                android:textColor="#22c064"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageShown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" /> 
</FrameLayout>
```

If i dont set imageView scale type to android:scaleType="fitXY" then it works but image doesnt fit screen.

I want to display image to fit between above bar which contains Text and below it has some icons. But if i make image scaletype ='fitXY' it doesnt display above text. Following is screenshot but i want image to occupy space
[image]

Comment: Please post more details about the results you have. "It doesn't work" is a little bit not enough to understand your problem. Also I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve - is it simply to display the image that fills the entire screen? BTW. Why do you want to use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`? Mostly people care about the aspect ratio, and with `fitXY` the ratio will not be maintained. Maybe you should use `centerCrop` or `centerInside` (depending on what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image to be below the `actionbar` you should not use the `FrameLayout` as a parent. You either should use vertical `LinearLayout` with weight or `RelativeLayout". Try following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleofscreen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Testing"
            android:textColor="#22c064"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageShown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I doubt that you use `fitXY` as `android:scaleType`, because it doesn't maintain the aspect ratio of the image - so your image will be deformed (stretched). In your case you should rather use `fitCenter`, but it depends on how exactly you want to scale your image - you can also play with `centerInside` or `centerCrop`.

Comment: didnot work :( I have used framelayout as my parent because it has many more components other than this

Comment: But what "doesnt work" in this solution? I've tested it and (if i understand you correctly) it works like you want it to work... Can you post your result, at least tell what doesn't work? Or post your code - you say that you cannot use this solution because of the rest of your code - so this "other code" is very important in order to propose any good solution. You cannot use `FrameLayout` for it, because you want your "actionbar" be in relation with this image (you want image BELOW the actionbar) so you have to use some layout that respects relations (either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`)

Comment: Either you will add extra parent (`LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) or your image will overlap your actionbar (this is not what you want). You could use FrameLayout is your actionbar will have fixed height - then you can set `layout_marginTop` on the `imageShown` image - it wont be displayed on top of actionbar then. But please post your code. BTW. doesn't `fitCenter` work for you (and what is the result)? This was your main question (how to fill the screen with image) so please refer to it somehow.

Comment: People here really want to help, but without enough details it's hard sometimes. Glad to see that I could help:) If this answer resolves your problem you should accept it (this will help another users to find a solution to their problems) and if it's also somehow useful for you, you can upvote it:)